# A txt file embeded inside an object tag gives an encoding error when an app is running?

Tags: html, tags, local, object-tag

I am trying to build an HTML app without a local server, just for that. Some of content, which is made of `txt` files, I embed inside `object` tags. The problem is, aside from being it right or not, is that I see an error

- File: `sum content`
- HTML: `html... <object data="file.txt"></object> html...`

Results in:

- Site: `html... <object ...>#document with sum content</object> html...`,
- Console: `... The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.`

The problem does not occure when I am running the site on a local server `python -m http.server`, which I expect is due to the server handling the protocols and encoding (?)

Without the server tho, when I changed the extension, both in the file and the tag, for `html`, there was no error at all, even when there were no tags in that file (like the one with charset, for example), but only text content. In both cases I saved the files in *Atom* with the same `UTF-8` encoding

Same situation is for `iframe` and `embed` tags.

So the question is why only changing the extension makes it error free and is there some more valid way, as I want to keep text files in the app structure.